# Windows 10 AppsFolder probably corrupted

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, filesystem-corruption

Well, I got myself a problem:

I wanted to temper some with the WindowsApps folder, changed permission to my account and now:

- None of the apps work anymore, e.g. mail
- None of the windows keyboard shortcuts work anymore
- Not even the start menu can open anymore

I tried resetting the permission to TrustedInstaller but that kept failing.

Any ideas...?

Comment: Performing a in-place repair should solve the problem, any other solutions, were made invalid when you changed the permissions on the folder.  Had you ask how to uninstall the applications before you did that we could have helped

Answer (score 0):

You most likely will need to replace the User Profile. In my own experience a Windows 10 Repair Install will not fix a damaged User Profile.

If you are no longer an Administrator, you will need to enable the built-in Administrator to make a new User Account which is a member of the Administrators group. I think I interpreted your post correctly on this score.

First back up any data you can to a USB drive. Be sure of this because you will likely wish to delete the damaged profile to create a new one of the same name.

Then follow the steps below to use the built-in Admin and create a new Admin Account. Be sure to disable the built-in Admin when you are finally running.

[Enable built in Admin](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-and-disable-the-administrator-account-in-windows-10/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20enable%20the%20Windows%2010%20Administrator%20account,%2Factive%3Ayes.%20...%206%20Type%20net%20user%20administrator.%20)

> **How to enable the Windows 10 Administrator account
> using the command prompt Enabling the Administrator
> account using the command prompt is the quickest and
> easiest method**.

==========

> Open a command prompt as an administrator by typing cmd in
> the search field.
>
> From the results, right-click the entry for Command Prompt,
> and select Run as Administrator.
>
> At the command prompt, type net user administrator.
>
> The value for Account Active should say No (Figure A).
>
> Type net user administrator /active:yes.
>
> You should receive a response that the command completed
> successfully.
>
> Type net user administrator.
>
> The value for Account Active should now say Yes (Figure B)

============

> **To create a new Account.**
>
> (1) Be sure to log into the existing account (I assume you can), back
> up all the data, email, favorites and so on to a USB drive.
>
> (2) Log into the Admin account, make a new Account and make it a
> member of the Administrators group.

If all the above does not work, then the only thing you can do now is reinstall Windows using a USB key made from the Media Creation Link.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

You can do a completely fresh install or you can run Setup from the USB Key and (at the appropriate spot) use the option to Keep Nothing. Any other option will keep your profile and keep the problem as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately this did not work for me, and in the new account nothing windows app and utility specific works. Any other ideas or might reinstallation be the only resort left?

Comment: There is sufficient damage that only a fresh install will fix it. I amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

@John - sorry but that's complete BS. Sufficient damage? It's a permission issue, there is no damage, just MS's overly complicated permissions policy. Advising someone to reinstall the complete OS is not a good answer and not somethin I would advise someone to do unless all other options are exhausted. Not to mention you reply doesn't address the initial problem at all, which is that the WindowsApps folder had undergone permission changes. This has nothing to do with the current user losing his admin privileges.

Here is something which will fix OPs problems - use AgentRev's WindowsAppsUnfukker, which was written to deal with exactly the issue at hand -> https://github.com/AgentRev/WindowsAppsUnfukker

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).